# C functions calling problems

Tags: c, function

I'm having trouble actually getting the function perform on the different variables. I don't know if it's because I defined it incorrectly but help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dmv(int x);

int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to DMV simulator 2014! \n");
    printf("Come forward first client");
    int z;
    int d;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int j;
    int e;
    int q;
    int s;
    dmv(int z);
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    int option;
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int f);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("We're closing");     
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int d);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int g);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int h);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int j);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int e);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int q);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Are there anymore people?");
    printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
    if(option == "yes")
    {
        dmv(int s);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We're closing");
    }
    printf("Alright we're closing!");

    return(0);
}

int dmv(int x)
{
    pritnf("Enter your name \n");
    char name;
    char Birthday;
    printf("Enter your DOB");
    scanf("%c" , name);
    scanf("%c" , Birthday);
    printf("Here is your lisence %d" , name);
}
```

Here are the errors i'm getting in cygwin.

```
Functionography.c:19: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:25: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:34: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:36: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:45: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:47: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:56: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:58: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:67: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:69: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:77: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:79: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:88: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:90: error: parse error before "int"
Functionography.c:99: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Functionography.c:101: error: parse error before "int"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of line 19?

Comment: You should really try out a new concept called *loops*.

Comment: There are a number of problems here, including some very basic syntax issues.

Comment: option shouldn't be an int, try char * or char[] and then use strcmp to compare option and your string literal - didn't read the rest sorry, multiple syntax problems

Answer (score 2):

The function should be called like:

```
dmv(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the dmv function is of type int, it should return some integer value. Otherwise use void return type for dmv function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a LOT of problem here:

- You copy/paste your code. You should NEVER do that. That s why functions and loop exists!
- `dmv(int z)` is a declaration, not a call. Once your function is declared, you just have to put the right type of variable. (`dmv(z)`)
- Your scanf aren t good. Either use a char array (`char birthday[5]`) or send the pointer to your variable (`scanf("%c", &birthday);`
- You don t catch what dmv is returning. Either do it return nothing (`void dmv`) or do something with the result.
- You try to get a string with `scanf("%c")`, it will return a char, not a string.
- You try to print a string with `printf("%d")`, that will print a decimal integer.
- You can declare multiple variable of the same type like this:

  int a,
      b,
      c,
      d;
- When doing printf, don t forget to add \n at the end, or the output will be unreadable.
- char is a simple character, it can handle "h", "i", or "a", or whatever is in the ascii table, but not "Hello" or other multiple character.
- As it is, your code will not care if you answer no. First because you don t ask any user input, second because you cant `==` a string, and third because you either branch of your if point to... the next "iteration".

Here the ameliorated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dmv(int x);

int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to DMV simulator 2014! \n");
    printf("Come forward first client");
    int i = 0,
        end = 0;
    int clients[5];
    char option[4] = "";
    do
    {
        dmv(int z);
        printf("Are there anymore people?");
        printf("If 'yes' say so otherwise say 'no'");
        scanf("%s", cache);
        if(strcmp(cache, "yes"))
        {
            client[i] = dmv(f);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("We're closing");
                end = 1;
        }
    }while(i < 5 || end = 1);

    return(0);
}

int dmv(int x)
{
    pritnf("Enter your name \n");
    char name[30];
    char Birthday[11];
    printf("Enter your DOB");
    scanf("%s" , name);
    scanf("%s" , Birthday);
    printf("Here is your lisence %s" , name);
}
```